# Autolayout shows warning message

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

i have some Problems with autolayout. Everything gets shown correct and everything works fine but i get some Warning Message in the Command Line:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 

(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't 
understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView 
property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6a60f0 H:[UIImageView:0xb645e40(75)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6d0e90 H:[UIView:0xb6c7350(220)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6aaea0 H:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0xb645e40]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0xb6c1590 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6c85c0 H:[UIView:0xb6c7350]-(7)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0xb6c1590 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6d2270 H:[UIImageView:0xb645e40]-(8)-[UIView:0xb6c7350]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xb6abd20 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0xb6c1590(300)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb6d0e90 H:[UIView:0xb6c7350(220)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView 
listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is how my nib File looks:

[image]

As you can see its a TableViewCell and i´m using a View (Sample Text) with a TextView(for iOS7) and a AttributedTextView (for iOS6)!

Whats the Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have conflicting constraints... Auto Layouts can be a pain in the .... sometimes.
When this happens to me, i usually clear all the constraints, and start all over by choosing clear all constraints.

You can also choose to "Add missing constraints" after that, and hope that XCode will automatically know what you want to do.. actually it's a 50-50 chance that XCode will get it right.

From your screen shot, it looks like you have too many constraints, so another option will be to try to remove then one by one, and to catch those "conflicting" constraints.

[image: clearing constraints]

Comment: I personally do not like using the option `Add missing constraints`. Its quite unpredictable, rather you should debug what is going wrong & clear it out yourself. Saves a lot time if X-Code screws up.

Comment: @footyapps27, generally speaking, you're right. But if you're head over heals with constraints - Adding missing constraints is a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Set for each view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; That is what he is trying to tell you. During runtime you have your contraints and the generic ones. Guess we will see this property switching to NO as default in a upcomming iOS version.

Comment: Thanks for your response, sadly nothing changed. I did: self.attributedTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; and self.messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Comment: It is the contentview that has the conflict: NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xb6abd20 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0xb6c1590(300)]>"